# trying to connect to a Raspberry pi server from windows using ssh causing: Connection timed out

Tags: linux, windows, ssh

i am using Raspberry for the first time but i wanted to create a ssh connection to a windows pc. both same network but it is causing ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.114 port 22: connection timed out.

those are the steps i followed:

- allow ssh connection from Raspberry
- ssh pi@192.168.0.114(and this is the ip of the Raspberry) from windows.

Comment: 1) can you ping the ip? 2) *How* did you "allow ssh connection from Raspberry"?

Comment: no i cannot ping, 100% dropped and i allowed it in the configuration of Raspbarry.

Comment: So the pi has either different IP address or there is some iptables rule/firewall.

Comment: the ip adress is correct i chekech it  a lot of times and i even disabled the firewall to troubleshoot the problem but still. just not working.